# trying to make a 4x4 list to user put they numbers

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a 4x4 and i don't know what is my problem Visual Studio Code is not showing me any error BUT my codes does not run.

```
for i in range(4):
    List.append([])
    print(f"List {i} numbers ...")
    for j in range(4):
        number = int(input(f"Enter Numbers for the List: {j}: "))
        List[i].append(number)
        
print("\nList: \n")
for n in List:
    print("List:" List)
```

Comment: You need to create the list before you can call `.append` on it.  For example, add this before the loop: `my_list = []`, then in the loop `my_list.append(value)`. I would also recommend not calling your list `list`.  Python doesn't protect keywords or names of functions/classes. My naming a variable `list`< your script loses the ability to call the existing `list()` constructor.

Comment: If this is your entire code, it's strange that you don't see an error. This code should through a `NameError` because of `List` being undefined.

Comment: Don't used keyword List. It valid for Python.

Comment: @toyotaSupra Python is case-sensitive, so `List` is different than `list`. Still not a great idea for humans though, since it's ambiguous and variables should usually be all-lowercase.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you're missing a comma after the "List:" in your final print statement.

Comment: Also, you probably want to print `n` instead of `List` and `List` isn't defined, before the first for loop, you'll need a `List = []`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).